# Write a .Net wrapper around AdbWinApi.dll

Tags: .net, android, dllimport, adb

I'm trying to write a wrapper around Android's AdbWinApi.dll.

I've run dumpbin on the DLL and found a number of entry points.  The problem is I don't really understand how to use those entry points and tie them up to the ADB API.

What is a good starting point to write this wrapper?

Comment: Are you trying to make the commands from adb.exe available in .net without having to launch the adb process? if so, check out http://madb.codeplex.com/ - it is a port (in progress) of the ddmslib which is what the ddms uses to communicate with adb. an adb server instance would still be needed via "adb start-server".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is from Ryan Conrad in the comment.

Are you trying to make the commands from adb.exe available in .net without having to launch the adb process? if so, check out madb.codeplex.com - it is a port (in progress) of the ddmslib which is what the ddms uses to communicate with adb. an adb server instance would still be needed via "adb start-server". – Ryan Conrad Jun 22 at 13:16